# Apache 2.4.6 unable to load PHP 5.5.4

Tags: php, windows, apache

I'm running apache 2.4.6 on Win64.
Have installed it on c:\apache24 as recommended.
The server runs with no problem :)

The, I have downloaded the php-5.5.4-nts-Win32-VC11-x86.zip and unzip it into c:\php directory.

I changed the httpd.conf file to include the following directives:
Line 176: LoadModule php5_module "c:\php\php5.dll"
Line 418: AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php

Now, when running the httpd server I'm getting the following error:
"httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 176 of C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load
c:\php\php5.dll into server: %1 is not a valid Win32 application."

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Close voter: This question is on-topic in my opionion since it "directly involves tools used primarily for programming." PHP totally fits this criteria!

Comment: This is essentially a server administration issue, not a programming one. (The issue is not solved by writing code.)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you used 32 Bit version of PHP, please see this link: http://www.apachelounge.com/download/additional/ and download compatible version.

Comment: Hi, I installed the 32 bit version due to the statement in the following page http://windows.php.net/download/ you can see that the 64bit version is still experimental??

Comment: Have just downloaded and installed the 64bit version and still having the same problem. Seems that something else is done wrong. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I was able to determine the problem and to fix it.
The issue is with the FCGI module that have to be configured in the apache configuration file httpd.conf.

Here is was I have put there that works for me:

```
LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so

<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>

   IPCCommTimeout 40
   IPCConnectTimeout 10
   MaxProcessCount 8
   OutputBufferSize 64
   ProcessLifeTime 240
   MaxRequestsPerProcess 500

   Alias /fcgi/ "C:/www/fcgi/"
   <Directory C:/www/fcgi/>   
      AddHandler fcgid-script .php
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
      FCGIWrapper "C:\php\php-cgi.exe" .php
      AllowOverride all
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
      Satisfy any
   </Directory>

</IfModule>
```